# На странице c iphone появляется боковой скролл, помогите разобраться

Tags: html, css

Знаю, что вопрос из разряда "сделайте все за меня" но я уже голову сломал...
2 абсолютно одинаковые страницы, смотрю через панель разработчика - нормально, с андроида - нормально. Как только открываю с iphone, то появляется боковой скролл.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

страницы одинаковые просто выводится разное содержимое.  но на верхней все нормально, на нижней беда...
это drupal нет необходимости прописывать

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

для каждой страницы, мне бы только разобраться, что их отличает друг от друга.

это ссылка на нормальную страницу: http://brandmission.ru/ourproduction

это ссылка на битую http://brandmission.ru/konsultacii

увидеть косяк можно только с телефона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос, оказалось, что у страниц не была задана минимальная высота, из за этого если контента было мало, и в нижней части появилось пустое пространство safari увеличивал страницу до того размера, пока контент не заполнит по высоте всю область. 
Решил вопрос задав медиазапросом минимальную высоту если сайт открыт в портретной ориентации.